# A function that search for an interface{} over a slice of interface{} in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a function that takes an element of any type and a slice of the same type and search the first inside the second, giving it's position as result or -1 otherwise.

I'm not a Go expert, so my first thought was to pass the element to search as interface{} and the slice as []interface{}, but it didn't really work.

Here's what I tried:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func IsElementInListWithPos(element interface{}, list []interface{}) int {
    for i := range list {
        if list[i] == element {
            return i
        }
    }

    return -1
}

func main() {
    list1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    list2 := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    pos1 := IsElementInListWithPos(3, list1)
    pos2 := IsElementInListWithPos("a", list2)
    fmt.Println(pos1, pos2)
}
```

It gives me the following errors:

```
cannot use list (type []int) as type []interface {} in argument to IsElementInListWithPos
cannot use list2 (type []string) as type []interface {} in argument to IsElementInListWithPos
```

Any idea how I could solve this issue without actually using two different functions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do that. As you noticed Go does not work that way. A []int and a []interface{} are totally different types. Major thing to remember here: `interface{}` does not mean "any type" it means "the empty interface" and nothing else. Writing such a function can be done with reflection and is complicated. Write two functions, or even three or four.

Comment: Take a look at the [sort package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) for how to do this kind of thing. That being said, writing two trivial functions is going to be a lot simpler.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice will explain why you cant do this

Comment: Thank you guys, of course in production I'm using many different functions, one for each type. I was just wondering how I could implement that as an exercise, so that I could understand more of how Go works. @Peter could you please explain me how the sort package could be useful in this case? Thank you John, that link was really helpful

Comment: The sort package in and of itself isn't useful (unless your slices happen to be sorted already), but it demonstrates how to use interfaces to implement algorithms. Applied to general linear search you end up with something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/FU1R8ZPa_yB. This shows how much more complicated this is compared to two trivial functions. Also note that you still have to write code for every type you want to support (more code, in fact, than the naive for loop).

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was more interested in the theory behind that, but your code is perfect for understanding what's happening behind the curtain. If you want you can write this exact same comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sort package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) demonstrates how interfaces can be used to implement algorithms in a type-independent way.

Linear search requires two essential operations that depend on the haystack element type, Len and Equal. So we can write the following Haystack interface and a Search function that using it:

```golang
type Haystack interface {
    Len() int
    Equal(int, interface{}) bool
}

func Search(haystack Haystack, needle interface{}) int {
    for i := 0; i < haystack.Len(); i++ {
        if haystack.Equal(i, needle) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

This makes writing implementations for Haystack simple, but not type-safe:

```golang
type Strings []string

func (s Strings) Len() int                        { return len(s) }
func (s Strings) Equal(i int, x interface{}) bool { return s[i] == x.(string) }

type Ints []int

func (s Ints) Len() int                        { return len(s) }
func (s Ints) Equal(i int, x interface{}) bool { return s[i] == x.(int) }

func main() {
    strings := []string{"b", "a", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Println(Search(Strings(strings), "c")) // 2
    fmt.Println(Search(Strings(strings), "e")) // -1

    ints := []int{2, 1, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println(Search(Ints(ints), 3)) // 2
    fmt.Println(Search(Ints(ints), 5)) // -1
}
```

Note the type assertions in the Equal methods. To make this type-safe we have to get rid of the `interface{}` argument to Equal:

```golang
type Haystack interface {
    Len() int
    Equal(int) bool
}

func Search(haystack Haystack) int {
    for i := 0; i < haystack.Len(); i++ {
        if haystack.Equal(i) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

type Strings struct {
    hs     []string
    needle string
}

func (s Strings) Len() int         { return len(s.hs) }
func (s Strings) Equal(i int) bool { return s.hs[i] == s.needle }

type Ints struct {
    hs     []int
    needle int
}

func (s Ints) Len() int         { return len(s.hs) }
func (s Ints) Equal(i int) bool { return s.hs[i] == s.needle }

func main() {
    strings := []string{"b", "a", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Println(Search(Strings{strings, "c"})) // 2
    fmt.Println(Search(Strings{strings, "e"})) // -1

    ints := []int{2, 1, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println(Search(Ints{ints, 3})) // 2
    fmt.Println(Search(Ints{ints, 5})) // -1
}
```

This made both the interface implementations and using the Search function much more complicated.

The moral of the story is that using interfaces this way requires a sufficiently complicated algorithm to be worth the trouble. If writing the interface implementation for a particular type is more work than writing the concrete implementation for the algorithm, well, then just write the concrete functions you need:

```golang
func SearchStr(haystack []string, needle string) int {
    for i, x := range haystack {
        if x == needle {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func SearchInt(haystack []int, needle int) int {
    for i, x := range haystack {
        if x == needle {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func main() {
    strings := []string{"b", "a", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Println(SearchStr(strings, "c")) // 2
    fmt.Println(SearchStr(strings, "e")) // -1

    ints := []int{2, 1, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println(SearchInt(ints, 3)) // 2
    fmt.Println(SearchInt(ints, 5)) // -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to build a solution that respects all your criteria. It will be possible once [generics](https://blog.golang.org/why-generics) are implemented. Or you could try building one using `reflect`, but that will yield a complex and potentially slow solution... so I generally advise against using `reflect` for something as simple as this (see second snippet below).

What you can do right now is to use something like:

```
func FindFirst(n int, f func(int) bool) int {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if f(i) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

// in your code (s is the slice, e the value you are searching for)
i := FindFirst(len(s), func(i int) bool {
    return s[i] == e
})
if i != -1 {
    // i is the index of the element with value e
}
```

This, as you can imagine, does not make much sense... as it's arguably simpler, faster, and **more idiomatic to simply write out the loop explicitly**:

```
// in your code (s is the slice, e the value you are searching for)
for i, v := range s {
    if v == e {
        _ = i // i is the index of the element with value e
        break
    }
}
```

Obviously, this whole approach (linear scan) is only reasonable if the number of elements in the slice is small. If your slice is big and changes rarely, it would arguably make more sense (from a time complexity perspective) to sort it ([`sort.Slice`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice)) first and then do binary searches ([`sort.Search`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search)) on the sorted slice. Or, alternatively, you could use a `map` instead: in which case (assuming keys are small) lookup would be O(1).